# Program solution reading through share folders

Tags: oracle, batch-file, plsql, oracle11g

I have a quick project I am working on for one of our VPs.

We have a few thousand CAD jobs stored on a network file share.  The file structure is such that there is a parent folder for the CAD job.  Part of the folder name contains the job number.  Inside the folder, there are 1 to many .ini text files that contain the connection information I need.

What I need is a programatic way to search through all the folders and extract the job number from the folder name, and all the connection values from the ini files.

For example for a folder named CM8252390-3, the job number is 8252390-3.  Inside this folder are 3 ini files.  Inside the ini files are that look like this:

```
[Connection]
Name=IMP_Acme_3.5
[Origin]
X=-15.044784
Y=19.620095
Z=44.621395
```

So my program needs to give me the following result

```
Job         Connection
8252390-3   IMP_Acme1_3.5
8252390-3   IMP_Acme2_3.5
8252390-3   IMP_Acme3_3.5
8254260-1   IMP_Acme3_2.4
8254260-1   IMP_Acme3_4.1
...continued for all folders in the network share
```

Any suggestion on the best way to do this.  I am primarily an Oracle PL/SQL developer, but have some basic Windows batch and Unix shell experience.  If I can get the data loaded into Oracle tables, I can search using PL/SQL tools, but is there a better way using shell, batch, or other tools?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a job for Powershell or vbScript.  It would be easy to use these tools to write the information you need to one file.

- This file should be written to an Oracle directory.
- grant read permission to a database user on this directory
- use utl_file to read the file or treat the file as an [external table](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i) and expose it as a view
- schedule a regular OS job to refresh or rebuild the list

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  Yeah if I can get the information written to one file, I can take care of the Oracle part.  Do you happen to have any Powershell or vbScript code samples?  I'll search the web.

Comment: My VB scripts are not accessible for another 10 hours.  I will add them later unless better answers come along

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  If I come across something, I'll update you here.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I found a solution using Powershell.  See this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107203/powershell-script-to-extract-folder-names-and-text-data-from-files/38116243#38116243

Comment: Excellent, Powershell is  superior to to vbscript for this once you get over the new permission model