# Powershell script to extract folder names and text data from files

Tags: powershell

I have a quick project I am working on for one of our VPs.

We have a few thousand CAD jobs stored on a network file share. The file structure is such that there is a parent folder for the CAD job. Part of the folder name contains the job number. Inside the folder, there are 1 to many .ini text files that contain the connection information I need.

I am looking for a Powershell solution to search through all the folders and extract the job number from the folder name, and all the connection values from the ini files.

For example for a folder named CM8252390-3, the job number is 8252390-3. Inside this folder are 3 ini files. Inside the ini files are that look like this:

```
[Connection]
Name=IMP_Acme_3.5
[Origin]
X=-15.044784
Y=19.620095
Z=44.621395
```

So my program needs to give me the following result

```
Job         Connection
8252390-3   IMP_Acme1_3.5
8252390-3   IMP_Acme2_3.5
8252390-3   IMP_Acme3_3.5
8254260-1   IMP_Acme3_2.4
8254260-1   IMP_Acme3_4.1
...continued for all folders in the network share
```

Looking for some Powershell samples on how to do this.  I am a Powershell newbie, so limited experience.  Some experience with Windows/DOS bat files, etc.

Thank you.

Update:

I made it a bit further.  Here is what I have so far.  It parses out the folder names into $job_num.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp\pwrshell | ForEach-Object -Process {  if ($_.PSIsContainer)
                                                              {
                                                                 if ($_.Name.Substring(0,2) -eq 'CM')
                                                                   {
                                                                     $job_num = $_.Name.Substring(4)
                                                                   }
                                                                 elseif ($_.Name.Substring(0,3) -eq 'Pri' -or 'Hyb' -or 'Had' -or 'Dmo')
                                                                   {
                                                                     $job_num = $_.Name.Substring(5)
                                                                   }
                                                                 $_.Name+' '+$job_num
                                                               }
                                                         }
```

Hoping someone can help out and give me the code for the ini file read.  If they wait for me to figure it out, the VP may find another solution.

Comment: Hi, try to write some code, include it in the question, and we will try to help.

Comment: Steps that I would do: Find directories, Parse the name, Get the INI files, Get the content. Try to put it in a script

Comment: Joe, please delete your (incomplete) answers, and edit your question to add your research. Answers will be posted by people willing to help.

Comment: sodawillow, I deleted my two answers and updated my question. Thanks for the guidance.  Hoping someone can help me with the reading of the files.

Comment: you get the content of a file with get-content -path PathToMyFile ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might provide the output you're looking for:

```
# // Declare an array to hold job objects
$aJobs = @()

Get-ChildItem C:\temp\pwrshell | ForEach-Object -Process {
    if ($_.PSIsContainer)
    {
        # // Store subfolder path in a variable
        $sFolderPath = $_.FullName

        if ($_.Name.Substring(0,2) -eq 'CM')
        {
            $job_num = $_.Name.Substring(2) # // Edited, value 4 returns incomplete string
        }
        elseif ($_.Name.Substring(0,3) -eq 'Pri' -or 'Hyb' -or 'Had' -or 'Dmo')
        {
            $job_num = $_.Name.Substring(5)
        }
        $_.Name+' '+$job_num

        # // Loop through all files in folder with .ini extension

        Get-ChildItem $sFolderPath | Where {$_.Extension -like '.ini'} | foreach {

            $sFilepath = $_.FullName

            # // Read file contents
            $aFiledata = Get-Content $sFilepath

            # // Loop through file lines, looking for line starting with Name=
            foreach ($sFileline in $aFiledata)
            {
                if ($sFileline.SubString(0,5) -eq 'Name=')
                {
                    $connection_name = $sFileline.SubString(5)

                    # // Create a custom PowerShell object to hold values
                    $JobObject = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
                        "Job"        = $job_num
                        "Connection" = $connection_name
                    }

                    # // Add job object to array
                    $aJobs += $JobObject
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

# // Display output
$aJobs | Format-Table Job,Connection
```

Comment: Drasen,thanks so much!  Perfect.  Just what I needed.